# windows xp, ntfs, reset corrupted folder permissions

Tags: windows-xp, ntfs, file-permissions

I open cmd prompt, CD to my userprofile folder, and run

```
CACLS .
```

This output (user account msala), they are the default correct permissions:

```
ASLBERGAMO\msala:F
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:F
BUILTIN\Administrators:F
ASLBERGAMO\msala:(OI)(CI)(IO)F
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)F
BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)F
```

Sometimes we found these permissions corrupted on our users workstations.
It breaks the applications accessing the userprofile and its subdirectories.

It seems to me

- XP builtin `CACLS` cannot fix OI CI IO settings
- `ICACLS` isn't available for XP

So, how can I solve ?

Answer (score 0):

#### ICACLS isn't available for XP

Use [Xcacls.exe - Display or modify Access Control Lists - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/xcacls.html) instead:

> Display or modify Access Control Lists (ACLs) for files and folders.
>   For Vista and greater use icacls.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
>   XCACLS filename [options]
>
>   XCACLS filename
> ```
>
> **Key**
>
> ```
>    If no options are specified XCACLS will display the ACLs for the file(s)
>
>    options can be any combination of:
>
>    /T       Traverse all subfolders and change all matching files found. 
>
>    /E       Edit ACL instead of replacing it. 
>
>    /x       Edit ACL instead of replacing it; affect only ACEs that this user already owns*
>
>    /R user  Revoke all access rights from the given user.
>
>    /D user  Deny specified user access, this will over-ride
>             all other permissions the user has.
>
>    /C       Continue on access denied errors. 
>    /Y       Replace user's rights without verify
>
>    /P user:permision[;FolderSpec]
>             Replace user's rights. see /G option below
>
>    /G user:permision[;FolderSpec]
>            Grant specified user access rights, permision can be: 
>            r  Read 
>            c  Change (write) 
>            f  Full control
>            p  Change Permissions (Special access)
>            o  Take Ownership (Special access)
>            x  EXecute (Special access)
>            e  REad (Special access)
>            w  Write (Special access)
>            d  Delete (Special access)
>            t  Used only by FolderSpec. see below
> ```

It can be downloaded from [How to use Xcacls.vbs to modify NTFS permissions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/825751/how-to-use-xcacls-vbs-to-modify-ntfs-permissions).

Comment: I am not sure about xcacls. see "Xcacls is the old tool (first an executable, then an unsupported vbScript). iCacls corrects issues with the older xcacls utilities"         https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/fad1c0cb-b7ce-4c74-bde3-15b415a1a4ef/icacls-or-xcacls-which-should-i-use?forum=winservergen

Comment: @Massimo Correct. But `icalcs` is not supported on Windows XP, so `xcacls` is the only possibility if you insist on using an outdated operating system.

Comment: ehm... I don't insist.I work in a government company, we are waiting for the budget to upgrade 500 pc.

Comment: @Massimo *shrug*